# Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

If I use path to get html contents, I face application has stopped error. But if I write HTML contents one by one in code line like "........", then program is run. Where is the problem?

Andriod file;

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String content = null;
    try {
        content = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\-SurrealBlack-\\Desktop\\b.html"), Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}
```

HTML file;

```
<html>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
        font: 0.9em Verdana, Arial, sans serif;
    }

    input, select, textarea {
        font: 0.9em Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    h2 {
        margin-top: 0.75em;
        font-size: 1.6em;
    }

    #leftcol {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 1em;
        padding: 0;
        width: 455px;
    }

    #map {
        width: 450px;
        height: 225px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #input {
        width: 450px;
    }

    #text {
        font-size: 0.85em;
        margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10em;
    }

    #info {
        position: relative;
        padding: 2em 0;
        margin-left: 470px;
    }

    #features {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #intersections {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, vectors, geojson, drawControls, selectControl, selectedFeature, polygonLayer;
    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Layer',
        {});
        polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");
        map.addLayers([baseLayer,polygonLayer]);      
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(polygonLayer,
            { onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect });
        drawControls = {
            polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
                        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
            point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
                        OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
            select: selectControl
        };
        for (var key in drawControls) {
            map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
        }

        geojson = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 1);
    }

    function toggleControl(element) {
        for (key in drawControls) {
            var control = drawControls[key];
            if (element.value == key && element.checked) {
                control.activate();
            } else {
                control.deactivate();
            }
        }
    }
    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        selectControl.unselect(selectedFeature);
    }
    function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
        selectedFeature = feature;
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                                 feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                 null,
                                 "<div style='font-size:.8em'>Feature: " + feature.id + "<br>Area: " + feature.geometry.getArea() + "</div>",
                                 null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }
    function onFeatureUnselect(feature) {
        map.removePopup(feature.popup);
        feature.popup.destroy();
        feature.popup = null;
    }


</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
   <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where on the phone or tablet is your file located? is it on a PC?! hmmm... then ask yourself why it doesn't access it!

Comment: do it need to permit to access file ?

Comment: I don't think you can access a path like C:\xyz\zxy.htm.

Comment: Put your file in the assets directory

Comment: I see you. Thank you so much, Tobor.

Comment: I added an answer with my "recipe" on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do like this, this is my "recipe":

Put your htm file in the assets folder of your device (emulated or physical)
Then access it like:

```
pgHelp = "file:///android_asset/help/help-" + lang + ".htm";

web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.htmlDisplay);
web.loadUrl(pgHelp);
```

My files are named help-xy.htm, where xy is a locale (en, de, fr, it, es),
stored in the lang variable.

As you can see, they are stored under a folder named "help" in the assets path